# Get all units of a particular dimensionality with pint

Tags: python, units-of-measurement

With [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), how can I filter the units in `pint.UnitRegistry` by dimensionality? For example, how could I get all units of mass type or of volume type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `get_compatible_units` method.

```
>>> ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

>>> ureg.get_compatible_units('[mass]')
frozenset({<Unit('electron_mass')>,
           <Unit('atomic_mass_unit')>,
           # .... many more
           <Unit('UK_ton')>,
           <Unit('long_ton')>})
```